.NET 8 Blazor web app with Web API using JWT authentication AuthorizationHandlerContext returns null
I have two .NET 8 project, an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and Blazor web app with interactive render mode set to server.
The Web API handles the authentication and provides a JWT token. The registration and login for getting a token works fine am trying to use permission base authorization using the sample from flexibleAuthorization.
The issue arises when I try to use @attribute [Authorize(Permissions.ViewAccessControl | Permissions.ConfigureAccessControl)] which returns a null authorizationHandlerContext user. I added it to a page.razor  as a basic test but I was then met with an errorwhen i navigate to the page
enter image description here
@page "/configurations"
@using EstateAllocator.Web.Authorization
@using EstateAllocator.Web.Client.Models.Roles
@attribute [Authorize(Permissions.ViewAccessControl | Permissions.ConfigureAccessControl)]

<main class="p-4 md:ml-64 h-auto pt-20">
    <EstateAllocator.Web.Components.Components.AccessControlComponent.RoleConfigurationComponent 
        />
</main>



        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
            services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
                .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();
            AddRootDirectory(services);
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                // Set validation parameters
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Validate issuer
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    // Validate audience
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    // Validate expiration
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    // Validate signature
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    // Set issuer
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").ToString(),
                    // Set audience
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience").ToString(),

                    // Set signing key
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        // Get our secret key from configuration
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey").ToString())),
                };
            });

            services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
            services.AddOutputCache();
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            services.AddAuthenticationCore();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, FlexibleAuthorizationPolicyProvider>();


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace EstateAllocator.Web.Authorization
{
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider(ProtectedLocalStorage localStorage) : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var token = (await localStorage.GetAsync<string>("authToken")).Value;
            var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) ? new ClaimsIdentity() : GetClaimsIdentity(token);
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return new AuthenticationState(user);
        }

        public async Task MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string token)
        {
            await localStorage.SetAsync("authToken", token);
            var identity = GetClaimsIdentity(token);
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }

        private ClaimsIdentity GetClaimsIdentity(string token)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            var claims = jwtToken.Claims;
            return new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwt");
        }

        public async Task MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
        {
            await localStorage.DeleteAsync("authToken");
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }
    }
}


using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EstateAllocator.Web.Client.Models.Roles;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace EstateAllocator.Web.Authorization;

public class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        var permissionClaim = context.User.FindFirst(
            c => c.Type == CustomClaimTypes.Permissions);

        if (permissionClaim == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(permissionClaim.Value, out int permissionClaimValue))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var userPermissions = (Permissions)permissionClaimValue;

        if ((userPermissions & requirement.Permissions) != 0)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}



Apparently it's a bug in .net 8 blazor webapp , incase any one is looking for a solution here's a link a to a thread that worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693596/unexpected-authorization-behaviour-in-a-blazor-web-app-with-net-8

I am investigating the same issue before in this thread and also found the  IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler workaround, but it's not a good answer I think.

@attribute [Authorize(Permissions.ViewAccessControl | Permissions.ConfigureAccessControl)] won't work here.

It works before the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider. So the "permission" claim is not added when pass the authorize pipeline.

We should use AuthorizeView, like below.
<AuthorizeView Roles="Your_Custom_Role">
    <Authorized>
        <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            //if not authorize redirect to somewhere
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"unauthorized");
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


Here is the realted links
1. Blazor Server .NET 8 with Windows Authentication and role authorization
2. blazor web app .net8 - negociate auth - http 403 when refresh page
